# What are the coordinates of the mysterious hole in Siberia?

Tags: coordinates, google-earth

I am interested in taking a Google Earth aerial view of the mysterious hole recently discovered in Siberia and perhaps doing some hydrological analysis of the area in a GIS.  However, there appears to be very little information on the actual coordinates of the hole.  What are the coordinates of this interesting geological feature?

More details on the Siberian hole:

- [Siberian Times](http://siberiantimes.com/science/casestudy/news/first-pictures-from-inside-the-crater-at-the-end-of-the-world/?comm_order=&c_page=4#comments)
- [NBC](http://www.nbcnews.com/science/weird-science/scientists-probe-depths-mysterious-hole-siberia-n159846)

[image]

Source: Associated Press

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting. A precursory search turned up that it's somewhere in the [Yamal Peninsula](http://tools.wmflabs.org/geohack/geohack.php?pagename=Yamal_Peninsula&params=70.67088_N_70.13672_E_). [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamal_Peninsula) has little to say about it as well.

Comment: "The giant hole appeared close to a forest some 30 kilometers from Yamal's biggest gas field Bovanenkovo.", you may get a radius from there?? Not precice, but may help ..

Comment: Obviously an ice generator for an expired crown. p.s. every grain of sand uses that hole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try ..

70°28'41.94"N

67°47'58.24"E

From [Here](http://www.sott.net/article/282161-Update-Russian-scientists-explore-site-of-crater-hole-in-Yamal-peninsula-Probably-result-of-internal-forces-not-seen-in-8000-years)

Comment: Thanks, that's probably it.  Landsat is the best imagery available in GE of the area, so nothing too exciting.

Comment: @Aaron It's possible something might show up in the near future on DigitalGlobe's gallery or the the NASA Earth Observatory. Then tend to post some imagery of current events - right now I don't see anything about the Yamal hole though.

Answer (score 4):

There might be multiple crater holes in this area. In a Russian language magazine [Science First Hand](http://sciencefirsthand.ru/c59_01_03.shtml) there is an [article](https://scfh.ru/en/papers/the-bermuda-triangle-of-yamal/) ([web-archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170815231626/https://scfh.ru/en/papers/the-bermuda-triangle-of-yamal/)) that mentions different coordinates, though the pictures look familiar.

The coordinates mentioned in the article are
69°58.268'N, 68°22.2'E

Below is an image taken as a screenshot from the Russian Federal Space Agency [portal](http://www.gptl.ru) that provides data from Russian Kanopus-V1 satellite that has a 2.1 meter resolution panchromatic camera.

[image]

The satellite image above agrees well with the Science First Hand article and with the video published in the Siberian Times [article](http://siberiantimes.com/other/others/features/large-crater-appears-at-the-end-of-the-world/).

[image]
Source: Science First Hand

You can see a lake just next to the place where the hole should be located, a creek running through the hole and passing by the lake, a series of smaller lakes on the opposite side of the creek. The image was taken on July, 18, 2013.

Answer (score 3):

Here you have some additional information on the location of the 2 new ones they found. Good luck and please come back with your findings" 
http://siberiantimes.com/science/casestudy/news/now-two-new-large-holes-appear-in-siberia/